How do I use a custom layout for specific routes
I am developing a React web-app using Next.JS, divided into 2 major parts, the user side, and admin side. I need to use a different layout for all of my admin pages, but I encounter a few problems.
This is the file structure :
├─ about-us/
│  └─ page.tsx
├─ admin/
│  ├─ tracking/
│  │  └─ create/
│  │     └─ page.tsx
│  ├─ AdminDashboardClient.tsx
│  ├─ layout.tsx
│  └─ page.tsx
├─ assets/
│  └─ images/
├─ careers/
│  └─ page.tsx
├─ contact/
│  └─ page.tsx
├─ fonts/
│  ├─ GeistMonoVF.woff
│  └─ GeistVF.woff
├─ shipping/
│  └─ page.tsx
├─ track/
│  └─ page.tsx
├─ favicon.ico
├─ globals.css
├─ layout.tsx
└─ page.tsx

admin/layout.tsx:
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Home, Package, Users, Settings } from 'lucide-react'

export const metadata = {
title: 'Admin Dashboard',
description: 'Shipping Company Admin Dashboard',
}

export default function AdminRootLayout({
children,
}: {
children: React.ReactNode
}) {
return (
   <html lang="en">
     <body className="bg-gray-100">
       <div className="flex min-h-screen">
          {/\* Sidebar \*/}

          {/* Main content */}
          <main className="flex-1 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto">
            <div className="container mx-auto px-6 py-8">
              {children}
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>

)
}

layout.tsx:
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className={`${geistSans.variable} ${geistMono.variable} antialiased`}
      >
        <Header />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

The general problem is that both the Header and Footer are loaded within the admin pages, besides the sidebar from the admin/layout.tsx. I believe this is also what causes Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML. on the admin pages. The header behaves weird, as it appears for one second, and then is removed
I am expecting to get a specific layout for the pages under admin route

The solution for this is to use Route segments.
By using html or body tag in layout you define a root layout.
You should have only one root layout. Or one per segment. But never one in the root and one in the segment. So here you would remove the app/layout and have one in each segment
From the docs:

Creating multiple root layouts
To create multiple root layouts, remove the top-level layout.js file, and add a layout.js file inside each
route group. This is useful for partitioning an application into
sections that have a completely different UI or experience. The 
and  tags need to be added to each root layout.

Structure:
  app
    (main)
      about-us
        page.jsx
      page.jsx
      layout.jsx # root layout
    (admin)
        admin
          tracking
            create
              page.jsx
      page.jsx
      layout.jsx # root layout


Also consider removing visual components from root layout and then nesting the layouts with the visual components. See how

